# Python: passing values from function to function

Tags: python, return

I've been fighting with this for three hours now.

**ETA- Should have mentioned this, but for purposes of this class, not allowed to use global variables.**

Within function main(), I want to run a function firstPass if and only if it's the first time the whole function is being run. The firstPass function initializes a couple variables and prints some information that is not interesting if it's not the first time you see it.

I duly have:

```
#Initialize variables that need to run before we can do any work here
count = 0

def firstPass():
    x = 5
    y = 2
    print "Some stuff"
    count = count + 1
    print "Count in firstPass is",count
    return count,x,y

def main ():
    print "Count in main is",count
    if count == 0:
        firstPass()
    else:
        #Do a whole bunch of other stuff that is NOT supposed to happen on run #1
        #because the other stuff uses user-modified x and y values, and resetting
        #to start value would just be self-defeating.

main()
```

This returns correctly on the first pass, but on subsequent passes, returns:

```
Count in main is 1
```

This is also a problem for my user-modified x and y values within other functions. Though I haven't modified them here, I did include them because I need to pass multiple values between functions later on in the code, but who wants to read all that when I could just put them here for the sake of the example...

I was under the impression that

```
return [variable]
```

passed the CURRENT (i.e. whatever that variable became within the current function) value of the variable back to other subsequent functions. Either my understanding is wrong, or I am just doing it wrong.

Comment: You need to understand how variable scope works in python, [namely global variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them).

Comment: Is this your actual code?  you need `def main` at least ...

Comment: The main of python looks something like `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: This seems like it would raise an UnboundLocalError ...

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, this is a class assignment, and we're not permitted to use global variables. Edited the post to put in a def in front of main, where I spaced out and forgot to add it.

Comment: @user2113818 You should probably include that important detail about not being able to use global variables in the question, as that's wht your code is trying to do.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, I just edited to say as much. You're right, that was important info.

Comment: Is `main()` going to be called multiple times? Typically `main()` runs just once.

Comment: No, I'm just calling it the once.

Comment: Why not pass arguments like main(count)?

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND- Thank you! Not sure that helps me better understand how the return statement works, but it certainly does help me with this particular situation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do:

```
def firstPass():
    global count
```

to get the `count` variable to update.

By using the `global` keyword you tell the interpreter to load and store the value into the global `count` variable instead of saving it to a local variable of the same name. For example:

I define two functions, one with and one without using `global`:

```
>>> a = 0
>>> def foo():
...   a += 1
...   return a
>>> def bar():
...   global a
...   a += 1
...   return a
```

After disassembling both functions using the [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module, it becomes apparent what the difference is:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 INPLACE_ADD         
              7 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3          10 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             13 RETURN_VALUE        

>>> dis.dis(bar)
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 INPLACE_ADD         
              7 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (a)

  4          10 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: +1 And then not try to do something crazy like return it as part of a tuple.

Comment: OP said he cannot use globals.

Comment: OP, cheerfully village-idioting it up when someone with more sense would be asleep, hadn't said that at the time Mike was posting. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of `return` is wrong.

The values returned aren't just inserted back into the namespace of the caller, they have to be received. They don't have to be received with the same name either.

```
count,a,b = firstPass()
```

Also I'd suggest passing the current `count` into the function as a parameter, rather than grabbing it from a global. It's just better style all around, and makes your functions easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to consider using a class.  It's a better container for maintaining state.

```
def firstPass():
    x = 5
    y = 2
    print "Some stuff"
    count = count + 1
    print "Count in firstPass is",count
    return count,x,y        

class MyActivityManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize instance variables"""
        self.run_count = 0

    def run(self):
        if not self.run_count:
            results = firstPass()
            self.run_count += 1
            # consider saving results in the instance for later use
        else:
            # other stuff


if __name__ == "__main__":
    runner = MyActivityManager()
    runner.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def firstPass(count):
    x = 5
    y = 2
    print "Some stuff"
    count = count + 1
    print "Count in firstPass is",count
    return count,x,y

def main():
    count = 0 # initialize it here; you're only running main once
    print "Count in main is",count
    if count == 0:
        count, x, y = firstPass(count) # sets the values from firstPass()
    else:
        #Do a whole bunch of other stuff that is NOT supposed to happen on run #1
        #because the other stuff uses user-modified x and y values, and resetting
        #to start value would just be self-defeating.

main()
```

However, if you want to initialize `count` outside of `main()`, use `main(count)`:

```
#Initialize variables that need to run before we can do any work here
count = 0

def firstPass(count):
    x = 5
    y = 2
    print "Some stuff"
    count = count + 1
    print "Count in firstPass is",count
    return count,x,y

def main (count):
    print "Count in main is",count
    if count == 0:
        firstPass()
    else:
        #Do a whole bunch of other stuff that is NOT supposed to happen on run #1
        #because the other stuff uses user-modified x and y values, and resetting
        #to start value would just be self-defeating.

main(count) # pass it as an argument
```

However, if you are only calling `main()` once, you can rewrite your code and general structure like this:

```
def main():
    count = 0
    count, x, y = firstPass(count) # no need to check if it is 0
    # do everything else

def firstPass(count):
    x, y = 5, 2 # multiple assignment, same as x = 5; y = 2
    print "some stuff"
    count += 1 # shorthand for count = count + 1
    print "Count in firstpass is", count
    return count, x, y

main()
```